# Bitshift operation with signed and unsigned

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I was doing a bitshift operation of an int and was surprised that it didn't come out as expected.

```
int i, res;
i = 0x80000000;
res = i>>1;                //results in 0xc0000000
res = (unsigned int) i>>1; //results in 0x40000000
```

how is it possible that a shift of a bit in an integer does only work to the 31st bit?

Comment: Are you sure that you got the comments right? Istn't it `0xc0000000` instead of `0x0c000000`?

Comment: that is both the same

Comment: Note: In `0x80000000;` MSB is set

Comment: @thebaconing: it's not the same -- count the number of zeros.

Comment: @thebaconing In `0xc0000000` MSB is `1` whereas in `0x0c000000` its `0`.

Comment: Thanks I almost haven't noticed it. corrected it already

Comment: Btw your spacing is misleading: `(unsigned int) i>>1` looks like it means `(unsigned int) (i>>1)` but it really means `((unsigned int) i)>>1` (cf. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence ), so it would be cleared if written as `(unsigned int)i >> 1` or better explicit `((unsigned int)i) >> 1` (or `((unsigned int)i)>>1` if you really don't like spaces), or even better in C++ `static_cast<unsigned int>(i) >> 1` (or `static_cast<unsigned int>(i)>>1`).

Comment: my question got already i don't know how many times altered. the begginning version was (unsigned int)i>>1. and I like the "I know what I am doing conversion" better for the lesser characters to write

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably [arithmetic bit shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

> when shifting to the right, the leftmost bit (usually the sign bit in
>   signed integer representations) is replicated to fill in all the
>   vacant positions (this is a kind of sign extension).

The [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.7§5 says:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value
>   is implementation-defined.

So the result could be anything the compiler writers decided it to be. They probably decided to extend the sign bit, the compiler doc should mention it.

Comment: implementation defined means the result is defined according to the docs of the compiler to be more precise