# Reading an int through char* buffer behaves different whether it is positive or negative

Tags: c++, binary-deserialization

**Background:** I was wondering how to (manually) deserialize binary data if we got them through a `char *` buffer.

**Assumptions:** As a minimal example, we will consider here that:

- I have only one `int` serialized through a `char*` buffer.
- I want to get the original `int` back from the buffer.
- `sizeof(int) == 4` on the target system/platform.
- The endianness of the target system/platform is *little-endian*.

**Note:** This is out of purely general interest therefore I don't want to use anything alike to `std::memcpy` because we'll not see the strange behaviour I encountered.

---

**Test:** I have built the following test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    // Create neg_num and neg_num_bytes then display them
    int neg_num(-5000);
    char * neg_num_bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&neg_num);
    display(neg_num, neg_num_bytes);

    std::cout << '\n';

    // Create pos_num and pos_num_bytes then display them
    int pos_num(5000);
    char * pos_num_bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pos_num);
    display(pos_num, pos_num_bytes);

    std::cout << '\n';

    // Get neg_num back from neg_num_bytes through bitmask operations
    int neg_num_back = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof neg_num; ++i)
        neg_num_back |= static_cast<int>(neg_num_bytes[i]) << CHAR_BIT*i; // For little-endian

    // Get pos_num back from pos_num_bytes through bitmask operations
    int pos_num_back = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pos_num; ++i)
        pos_num_back |= static_cast<int>(pos_num_bytes[i]) << CHAR_BIT*i; // For little-endian

    std::cout << "Reconstructed neg_num: " << neg_num_back << ": " << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT*sizeof neg_num_back>(neg_num_back);
    std::cout << "\nReconstructed pos_num: " << pos_num_back << ":  " << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT*sizeof pos_num_back>(pos_num_back) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Where `display()` is defined as:

```
// Warning: num_bytes must have a size of sizeof(int)
void display(int num, char * num_bytes)
{
    std::cout << num << " (from int)  : " << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT*sizeof num>(num) << '\n';
    std::cout << num << " (from char*): ";
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof num; ++i)
        std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(num_bytes[sizeof num -1 -i]); // For little-endian
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output I get is:

> ```
> -5000 (from int)  : 11111111111111111110110001111000
> -5000 (from char*): 11111111111111111110110001111000
>
> 5000 (from int)  : 00000000000000000001001110001000
> 5000 (from char*): 00000000000000000001001110001000
>
> Reconstructed neg_num: -5000: 11111111111111111110110001111000
> Reconstructed pos_num: -120:  11111111111111111111111110001000
> ```

I know the test case code is quite hard to read. To explain it briefly:

- I create an `int`.
- I create a `char*` array pointing the first byte of the previously created `int` (to simulate that I have a real `int` stored in a `char*` buffer). Its size is consequently 4.
- I display the `int` and its binary representation
- I display the `int` and the concatenation of each bytes stored in the `char*` buffer to compare that they are the same (in reverse order due to endianness purposes).
- Try to get the original `int` back from the buffer.
- I display the reconstructed `int` as well as its binary representation.

I performed this procedure for **both negative and positive values**. This is why the code is less readable as it should be (sorry for that).

---

As we can see, the negative value could be reconstructed successfully, but it did not work for the positive one (I expected `5000` and I got `-120`).

I've made the test with several other negative values and positive values and the conclusion is still the same, it works fine with negative numbers but fails with positive numbers.

**Question:** I'm in trouble to understand why does concatenating 4 `chars` into an `int` via bit-wise shifts change the `char` values for positive numbers when they stay unchanged with negative values ?

When we look at the binary representation, we can see that the reconstructed numbers is not composed of the `char`s that I have concatenated.

Is it related with the `static_cast<int>` ? If I remove it, the integral promotion rule will implicitly apply it anyway. But I need this to be done since I need to convert it into an `int` in order to not lose the result of the shifts.
If this is the heart of the issue, how to solve it ?

---

**Additionally:** Is there a better way to get back the value than bit-wise shifting ? Something that is not dependent to the endianness of the system/platform.

*Perhaps this should be another separate question.*

Comment: When you do bit-fiddling using `signed int` and `signed char`, you may have a lot of undefined and/or defined but "weird" behavior when some of the sign-bits are set. The safest in your case, is to use `unsigned` everywhere and convert the result to `signed` when you are finished.

Comment: In addition to @HAL9000's comment, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18631651/1753435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main things that affect the outcome here:

- The type `char` can be signed or unsigned, it's an implementation detail left to the compiler.
- When integer conversion happens, signed values are sign-extended.

What is probably happening here is that `char` is signed on your system and with your compiler. That means when you convert the byte to an `int` and the high bit is set, the value will be sign-extended (for example binary `10000001` will be sign-extended to `1111111111111111111111111000001`).

This of course affect your bitwise operations.

The solution is to use an explicit *unsigned* data type, i.e. `unsigned char`. I also suggest you use `unsigned int` (or `uint32_t`) for your type-conversions and temporary storage of the data, and only convert the full result to plain `int`.

Comment: There are some crazy problems with strict aliasing that make using `uint8_t` technically undefined behavior.  OP should stick with `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `static_cast<int>(pos_num_bytes[i])` will return a negative int in some of your cases.

You can replace the last loop with this, if you want to see the issue:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pos_num; ++i)
{
    pos_num_back |= static_cast<int>(pos_num_bytes[i])  << CHAR_BIT * i; // For littel-endian
    std::cout << "\pos_num_back: " << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof pos_num_back>(pos_num_back) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof pos_num_bytes[i]>(pos_num_bytes[i]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof pos_num_back>(static_cast<int>(pos_num_bytes[i])) << std::endl;

};
```

or you can run this maybe to have the intended result ?

```
// Get pos_num back from pos_num_bytes through bitmask operations
int pos_num_back = 0;
char* p_pos_num_back = (char*)(&pos_num_back);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pos_num; ++i)
{
    p_pos_num_back[i] |= pos_num_bytes[i];
};
```